# Simulating Alt + Tab Key Press

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, alt-tab

I have tried to simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press using `SendInput`, `keybd_event`, `SendMessage` and `SendKeys.Send` but none of them work. All other key presses work but only <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how do I open the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Task Switcher programatically?

Comment: This link looks like it might be helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4b6dbc43-a026-4957-9178-91d2001e2d0d/windows-8-block-alttab-simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that looks like it may be helpful and useful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4b6dbc43-a026-4957-9178-91d2001e2d0d/windows-8-block-alttab-simulation

Comment: this is ages old, but it  needs to put the solution in the answer, not just a link

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28vs.80%29.aspx) class and it’s `Send` method

Comment: `SendKeys.Send("%{Tab}")`, right? Doesn't work for me in Windows 8.1. Does it work for you?

Comment: there is problem in passing Alt+Tab in Win 8. See a workaround http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4b6dbc43-a026-4957-9178-91d2001e2d0d/windows-8-block-alttab-simulation#291eb5b4-f6d2-49b6-83db-658bd832f2c9